# Get Data with range of price between min and max in java elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search , i am reading the doc so far its good but i am not able to write a method to get by range, Below is a method that gets by ID which works perfectly but how can i do this to get a list of data that match the price range.

```
 public Map<String, Object> getTourById(String id){
        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(INDEXTOUR, TYPETOUR, id);
        GetResponse getResponse = null;
        try {
            getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = getResponse.getSourceAsMap();
        return sourceAsMap;
    }
```

Above method works fine now below is the method to get by range and return datas that matches the price

```
 public Map<String, Object> getTourByPriceRange(int minPrice, int maxPrice) {

        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(INDEXTOUR, TYPETOUR, "requires an ID");

        QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
                .rangeQuery("price")
                .from(minPrice)
                .to(maxPrice)
                .includeLower(true)
                .includeUpper(true);

        GetResponse getResponse = null;
        try {
            getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = getResponse.getSourceAsMap();

        return sourceAsMap;
    }
```

Only the query builder is accurate in the above method, the result i want to get is a bunch of data that price fall in the range given.

```
{
    "departure": {
      "city": "\u0438\u043d\u0441\u043a",
      "date": "2018-08-10"
    },
    "extras": [],
    "hotel": {
      "beach": {
        "distance": 0,
        "type": "\u041f\u0435\u0447\u0430\u043d\u044b\u0439"
      },
      "country": "\u0413\u0440\u0446\u0438\u044f",
      "distanceToAirport": 0,
      "facilities": [
        "Standard Without Balcony"
      ],
      "food": "\u0422\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u0437\u0430\u0432\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043a\u0438",
      "photoUrl": "https://s1.tez-tour.com/hotel/7021893.jpg",
      "regionName": "\u0425\u0430\u043b\u043a\u0438\u0434\u0438\u043a\u0438 - \u041a\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0440\u0430",
      "stars": 4,
      "title": "KALLIKRATEIA"
    },
    "nights": 8,
    "people": 1,
    "price": 2595 // i want to use price as parameters for the search method
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good job so far!! In order to issue a search request you need to use `SearchRequest` and not `GetRequest` which is meant to retrieve a single document by ID.

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
            .rangeQuery("price")
            .from(minPrice)
            .to(maxPrice)
            .includeLower(true)
            .includeUpper(true);

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEXTOUR); 
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
    searchSourceBuilder.query(qb); 
    searchRequest.types(TYPETOUR);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder); 

    SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {
        searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
```

Comment: what should i be returning in this method ? @Val , in your try method i see getResponse with no class just reference

Comment: SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
        try {
            searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }

Comment: I've fixed my answer and here is what you can do with `SearchResponse`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-response

Comment: and what should i return in other to get data , my method is of type Map

Comment: Check the link I gave you, there are detailed examples